# Converting formatted string to integer in Javascript

Tags: javascript, integer

how can i convert "570.581,88" into an integer and sort accordingly?

Comment: A single integer? What's that comma doing there?

Comment: How will you convert "100.99" to an int?

Answer (score 12):

```
var s = "570.581,88";

// Format as American input
s = s.replace(/\./g,'').replace(',','.');

// Integer
var i = parseInt(s,10);

// Floats
var f1 = parseFloat(s);
var f2 = s*1;
var f3 = +s;
```

Comment: Is there a locale neutral way of doing this? If my one person's locale is European and the other is American, will parseInt work differently?